# How to print current attribute value with xslt 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt

Here's my data structure in XML:

```
<MyFile>
    <Body>
        <Data>
            <row A="1" B="SPC" C="011" D="" E="0" F="38.482" />
            <row A="2" B="CDR" C="011" D="" E="0" F="39.812" />
            <row A="3" B="FFD" C="011" D="" E="0" F="41.115" />
        </Data>
    </Body>
</MyFile>
```

Here's how I got so far:

```
<xsl:for-each select='/MyFile/Body/Data/row'>
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
          <xsl:text><![CDATA[*]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I guess I'm in the right way because I do print * for 3x6=18 times!

the question is how do I replace * with attribute value like "SPC"、"38.482"

any help? THX!

Comment: You can simply do `<xsl:value-of select="." />` here (and you wouldn't need `<xsl:text>` in this case either), although that would give you the values of attributes as one long string. If you wanted something else, it may help if you showed the output you were expecting in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you want to get as output.

Comment: THX for reminding, what I want is like this: 1;SPC;011;;0;38.482;2;CDR;011;;0;39.812;3;FFD;011;;0;41.115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select='/MyFile/Body/Data/row'>
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
          <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is

```
1;SPC;011;;0;38.4822;CDR;011;;0;39.8123;FFD;011;;0;41.115
```